# How can I list websites on IIS7, from script, without using IIS6 compat pack (WMI veneer)

Tags: javascript, iis-7, windows-installer

On IIS6, I can use WMI to list available websites, like this:

```
    var iis = GetObject("winmgmts://localhost/root/MicrosoftIISv2");
    var query  = "SELECT * FROM IIsWebServerSetting"

    // get the list of virtual servers
    var results = iis.ExecQuery(query);

    for(var e = new Enumerator(results); !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
        var site = e.item();
        // site.Name                   // W3SVC/1, W3SVC/12378398, etc
        // site.Name.substr(6)         // 1, 12378398, etc
        // site.ServerComment)         // "Default Web Site", "Site2", etc
        // site.ServerBindings(0).Port // 80, 8080, etc
    }
```

I know I can [run this script on IIS7, if I have previously installed the IIS6 Compatibility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338663/web-setup-msi-fails-on-windows-server-2008).

Is it possible to get the list of WebSites without requiring the compatibility pack as a pre-requisite?

I know I can run AppCmd to do this from the command line:

```
\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list sites
```

But... can I run that from a custom action in an MSI? 
And... if not, how can I do the equivalent thing (list websites on IIS7) from javascript?

---

**EDIT**
Here's how I tried running the command from within Javascript.

```
function GetWebSites_IIS7()
{
    var ParseOneLine = function(oneLine) {
        ...a bunch of regex parsing here....
    };

    LogMessage("GetWebSites_IIS7() ENTER");
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var windir = shell.Environment("system")("windir");
    // aka Session.Property("%WINDIR%")

    var appcmd = windir + "\\system32\\inetsrv\\appcmd.exe list sites";
    var oExec = shell.Exec(appcmd);

    var sites = [];
    while (!oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream) {
        var oneLine = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine();
        var line = ParseOneLine(oneLine);
        LogMessage("  site: " + line.name);
        sites.push(line);
    }

    return sites;
}
```

This works, but it briefly pops a visible console window, which then disappears. Doesn't look very polished.  I think I can avoid the console window by using `shell.Run()` instead of `shell.Exec()`.  But `shell.Run()` doesn't give access to the stdout, so I would have to redirect the output to a temporary file, then read the output.  I haven't tried that yet. That may introduce some security issues; I'll have to see.

---

Related:
[Where and how should my CustomAction create and read a temporary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395056/wix-where-and-how-should-my-customaction-create-and-read-a-temporary-file/5397662#5397662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run appcmd from the custom action the same way you do any custom action which runs exe. First off, you should author a [DirectorySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_directorysearch.htm)/[FileSearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_filesearch.htm) elements to find the full path to the executable. Next, add a custom action with [ExeCommand attribute](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_customaction.htm). You're probably trying to get feedback from a user, so leave it immediate. Also, think about using [QuietExec](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm) in order not to show console window to your users.

By the way, if my guess is correct, you're trying to do [something like this](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2011/02/23/web-application-installer-in-wix.aspx). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to author a setup program in Wix that allows the user to select a website. Similar to that blog entry. But I am not pre-requiring .NET Framework - my setup needs to run on server core and prior versions of Windows Server - so I cannot use the approach described in that post with the System.Administration .NET classes. I know I can use ExeCommand to run commands, but I cannot figure out how to capture *the output* of the command I execute, which is what I am interested in.  I guess I could stuff the output into a temporary file and then read it; that raises additional issues.

Comment: By the way, I did this, and it worked. I ran appcmd from Javascript, redirected the stdout, and parsed the output.  No problems.  You can see the code here: https://iirf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/99885#1624772.  Look for the function `GetWebSites_Appcmd()`.